# Checkboxes to indicate inclusion in a list?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables, called `Machine` and `Type`. Since they have a many-many relationship, I have a `MachineType` resolution table in my DB. No problem.

The end user needs to be able to manage these - create new types and assign them to machines. I have an `XtraGridView` that I am using to display the `Machine` as master and `Type` as detail.

Initially I used a `Lookup` to add `Type` dropdowns to the `MachineType` detail view. But that creates duplicates and is not the best way to display this information. I'd like a series of checkboxes (one for each `Type` options available) so the user can click the appropriate ones for each machine, thus avoiding duplicates. Upon saving, the appropriate `MachineType` rows can be generated.

I was going to just code this manually but if there's some kind of binary collection mapping in either DevExpress or the .net framework I can use, I'd prefer that than to reinvent the wheel.

Cheers

EDIT: [This](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/320471/PostAttachment.aspx) is what I mean. From [this thread](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/93112/320468.aspx#320468). However, they store it as a collection (a string delineated by commas) and not a series of DB rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you interested in just returning the values to bind to as a linq query?

```
from m in Machine
from t in Type
select new {m,t}
```

This will give you a cross join for each of the pairings
on save you can just check to see if the MachineType table has the pairing already

```
from mt in MachineType
where mt.MachineId == <machine from list>
&& mt.TypeId == <type from list>
```

if you want to pass the query lists you can send a list of pairings you can send a dictionary and loop through it or use the `Contains()` function if dictionaries support that.